# Why is $div(z)$ well-defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading Fulton's algebraic curves book and I didn't understand why divisors of $z \in K$ are well-defined (page 97):

[image]

The problem he mentioned:

[image]

I didn't understand why solving this problem we have the well-definiteness of $div(z)$.

I really need help!

Thanks

Comment: Being well-defined here just means that the sum should be finite. So which terms in the sum are non-zero?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the points which are zeros or poles?

Comment: Right, as those are the ones where $z$ has non-zero order.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, of course.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm sorry but I don't understand yet the relation with this and the problem 4.17.

Comment: So it seems that he wants you to conclude from that exercise that the set of poles of $z$ is finite (I don't recall enough algebraic geometry to see if that is trivial from the set being algebraic in a projective variety).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I hope someone appears to help me with this, thank you.

Comment: Downvote for extreme laziness (posting scans instead of rewriting the question, thus making it much more searchable and editable).

Comment: @5xum I did it on purpose! I wanted to emphasize which part of the book I have doubts, maybe someone could find in the same book the solution of my problem.

Comment: @5xum However I respect your decision to downvote me, your worries are legit.

Comment: In the top box it's clear we're talking about divisors on a curve. The algebraic sets of a curve are the finite sets.

Comment: @JohnBrevik did you mean the author is considering $V$ as a curve?

Comment: @user42912 No, in the bottom box $V$ is any variety.

Comment: @JohnBrevik I think I didn't understand what you meant by "The algebraic sets of a curve are the finite sets". Let's pick for example this curve $C:Y=X$. Obviously, $V(C)$ is not finite.

Comment: @user42912 Sorry, I meant the proper algebraic subsets.

Comment: @JohnBrevik I'm sorry, but I'm still having problems to understand your reasoning. In our case $V$ is any variety (not necessarily an algebraic set of a curve). The fact of the pole set of $z$ is an algebraic subset of $V$ doesn't say anything to me.

Comment: @user42912 In the exercise, $V$ can be any variety, including a curve. The first box above references the exercise in the specific case of a curve.

Comment: @JohnBrevik I think I got it! Let's call $P$ the pole set of $z$. In the exercise (second box) we have $z\in k(V)\implies P\subset V$. In our case, we have $V=C$, where $C$ is a curve. Since $z\in k(C)$, then by the exercise we have $P\subset C$, Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24044/discussion-between-john-brevik-and-user42912).

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble getting logged in to chat. Anyway, yes, that's the idea!

Comment: @JohnBrevik No problems. Thank you very mucho for helping me!